# how to improve the quality of screenshot took by exportImage() function in videojs-record

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, videojs-record

```
// video.js configuration
    this.config = {
      controls: false,
      bigPlayButton: false,
      loop: false,
      width: 640,
      height: 480,
      fluid: false,
      plugins: {
          record: {
              screen: true,
              image:true,
              maxLength: 30,
              displayMilliseconds: false,
              debug: true,
          }
      } 
    };
async getVPDetails(): Promise<any> {
    return await this.player.record().exportImage('image/png', 1);
  }
  takeScreenshot(){
      this.getVPDetails().then(data => {
          var unsafeImageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data);
          this.imageData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(unsafeImageUrl);
      }, error => {
          console.log(error);
      
      });
  }
```

this is my code i used to take a screenshot of the screen (whole window) but the quality is very low[showed in the image i have took from this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Q1v.png)
can someone help me to increase its quality.
library used: https://collab-project.github.io/videojs-record/#/

Comment: Seems like you need to increase dimensions. Go to API's docs for more details.

Comment: not proper information present regarding quality

Comment: According to https://collab-project.github.io/videojs-record/#/options default frame size is 320x240px - try to modify it

Comment: @biesior not woriking...

Comment: Try to publish complete sample code you're using somewhere, so one can take an overall look